# Save image with all kind of extension

Tags: php, jquery, image, jcrop

I am using `jcrop` in my Wordpress project. I was wondering how to save the image with its original extension. Like my code only works for `jpg` image. I am saving the cropped image to server. Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['saveCrop']))
{

    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;
    $src = plugins_url( "employee/uploads/".$_POST['imgName'] , dirname(__FILE__) );
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    @imagejpeg($dst_r, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/plugins/employee/uploads/".$_POST['imgName'], $jpeg_quality);
    //imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

}
```

If I try with `png` image, I get a black one. Same thing happens for `gif`. How can I get it to work with all extensions and save with its original extension (jpg for jpg, png for png).
**Update::**
**ok.. for creating png file i was trying this code. I am sure i am doing something wrong:**

```
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/png');
@imagepng($dst_r, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/plugins/employee/uploads/".$_POST['imgName'], $jpeg_quality);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $imageObject = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile); //Your jpg image created with your code
    imagegif($imageObject, $imageFile . '.gif');
    imagepng($imageObject, $imageFile . '.png');
    imagewbmp($imageObject, $imageFile . '.bmp');
?>
```